# Different Value from first select and second select (UNION WITH GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, union

I have a table **users**:

```
user_id | ui_id
--------+-------
   4    |   16
--------+-------
   5    |   17
--------+-------
   9    |   21
```

**user_info**:

```
ui_id |      fname      |     lname
------+-----------------+--------------
  16  |     Joanalyn    |    Lalicon
------+-----------------+--------------
  17  |   Jose Allan    |   Dela Cruz
------+-----------------+--------------
  21  |       Steve     |   Dela Cruz
```

**overtime**:

```
ot_id | approve_by
------+------------
  3   |     4
------+------------
  6   |     9
------+------------
  8   |     5
------+------------
  9   |     9
------+------------
  16  |     4
```

And finally **loa**:

```
loa_id| approve_by
------+------------
  4   |     9
------+------------
  6   |     4
```

I want to get the `Full Name`, `qty`, and `qty2` as a field in one query. But can't get it working. I can get the sum of ot_id count and loa_id count but can't get the value as separated.

my query:

```
SELECT name,qty2 <---- value from second select
FROM
(SELECT CONCAT(ui.fname,' ',ui.lname) AS name,
        COUNT(o.ot_id) AS qty
FROM overtime o
INNER JOIN users u ON o.approve_by=u.user_id
INNER JOIN user_info ui ON u.ui_id=ui.ui_id
GROUP BY ui.ui_id

UNION ALL

SELECT CONCAT(ui.fname,' ',ui.lname) AS name,
        COUNT(l.loa_id) AS qty2 <----- can't get this value
FROM loa l
INNER JOIN users u ON l.approve_by=u.user_id
INNER JOIN user_info ui ON u.ui_id=ui.ui_id
GROUP BY ui.ui_id) ui

GROUP BY name
```

I can't get the `qty2` but `qty` is working. And if I select `SUM(qty)` it will sum up the `ot_id` and `loa_id`

I want something like this:

```
       Name          |        qty       |       qty2    
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
  Joanalyn Lalicon   |        2         |         1
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
 Jose Allan Dela Cruz|        1         |         0
---------------------+------------------+-------------------
   Steve Dela Cruz   |        2         |         1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(ui.fname, ' ', ui.lname) AS name
     , COUNT(o.ot_id) AS qty
     , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM loa WHERE approve_by = u.user_id) AS qty2
  FROM users u
  JOIN user_info ui ON ui.ui_id = u.ui_id
  LEFT JOIN overtime o ON o.approve_by = u.user_id
 GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c81e/3/0)**

Comment: (Slaps face) Thanks! :D

Comment: Wait. I have a problem here. Even the `loa` has a data but if the `overtime` haven't, row won't be shown.

Comment: @LekzFlores update the count to `COUNT(o.ot_id)` and do a `LEFT JOIN` on `overtime`